# disable zooming with a small number of points

Tags: lightweight-charts

Faced the problem of disabling the zoom with a small number of points. How can I disable further zooming if the number of points to fit on the canvas is less than 10, for example?

Comment: Found how this can be done by changing the maxBarSpacing parameter to a lower number.

Comment: You can use `fixLeftEdge` and `fixRightEdge` options as well I think. Have you tried to use them?